# The "inverse" method of getParameter()

Tags: java, servlets, httpurlconnection

One way of sending the user parameters is appending them to the URL:

```
URLAddress+="?param1=value1+param2=value2"
```

How else can i send user parameters to the server? These are the params to be read by the HttpServletRequest method

```
getParameter(param1);
```

on the receiver's end.

I tried

```
setRequestProperty("param1","value1");
```

of *HttpURLConnection*. However, *getParameter()* couldn't find them on the request.

I am trying to send them outside th URL so that they won`t be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only two possibilities: Either append them to the URL in case of GET request, then they are visible, or write them as the body in case of POST request:

```java
/**
 * Convert a Map to a query string.
 * @param values the map with the values
 *               <code>null</code> will be encoded as empty string, all other
 *               objects are converted to
 *               String by calling its <code>toString()</code> method.
 * @return e.g. "key1=value&key2=&email=max%40example.com"
 */
public static String queryString(Map<String, Object> values) {
    StringBuilder sbuf = new StringBuilder();
    String separator = "";

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : values.entrySet()) {
        String value = entry.getValue() == null
                ? "" : String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
        sbuf.append(separator);
        sbuf.append(urlEncode(entry.getKey()));
        sbuf.append('=');
        sbuf.append(urlEncode(value));
        separator = "&";
    }

    return sbuf.toString();
}

static String urlEncode(String value) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

In case of POST, you have to set the header `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I recommend using 'UTF-8' as encoding. If this is not appropriate for you, you have to dig how to handle different encodings.

So instead of

```
http://www.example.com/path/resource?abc=124&xyz=John+Doe
```

you write the body:

```
abc=124&xyz=John+Doe
```

Setting parameters as headers (`addRequestHeader()`) should not be done, since most middleware (e.g. web application firewall, proxy, load-balancer) parse the headers and you could conflict with pre-defined headers.

The above code is taken from [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/). There you can see a list of libraries which can ease your life when you have to deal with HTTP requests and don't want to use `HttpURLConnection` natively.

Why did I add the code for building a query string?

You can read many questions here on SO where the mistake was that they didn't encode parameter names or values correctly.

Comment: is there a direct way of extracting this from the body? if not, why put them into the same form as the one appended to url?

Comment: Have a look at [getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)). You can tell no difference whether the parameter came from the query-string or the POST body.